# Checking system date

Tags: bash, shell

New to stack overflow , New to shell scripting . I just want to know how to check the system date ?  If the system date exceeds the desired date the script should exit if not then execute rest of the script . It will work like license verification . Its very simple though but I am no geek . Need help desperately. 
If anybody can spoonfeed me as its very easy to perform this action in shell script .

Answer (score 0):

date command and a little math will do the job
`date +%s` produces number of seconds  since unix epoch.
i code in a verbose and expressive way

you should replace the echo part with your own code

```
#!/bin/bash
ExpiringTime=$(date +%s -d "Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 CST 2020")
NowTime=$(date +%s -d "now")

if  ((ExpiringTime-NowTime < 0)) ;
    then
    echo Expired
else
    echo Not expired
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
system_date=`date`
given_date="2019-09-19 22:38:46"
given_date_ts=$(date -d "${given_date}" +"%s")
system_date_ts=$(date -d "${system_date}" +"%s")

if [ $system_date_ts -ge $given_date_ts ];
then
  echo 'System date greater'
else
  echo 'System date smaller'
fi
```

You can do your code accordingly in if else blocks.